# manipulate result after join table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

i have a query, I write a query and join various tables in codeigniter and getting the array like below:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
            [MRID] => 1
            [MSR_Name] => John
            [MSR_email] => john@gmail.com
            [MSR_mobile] => 9000000008
            [MSR_hqdetail] => kjjh
            [hqdetail_id] => 1
            [doctor_id] => 1
            [dr_msl_no] => DOC000012
            [doctor_name] => Y K Singh
            [dr_email] => yksingh@gmail.com
            [chemist_id] => 1
            [chemist_name] => Abhishek Srivastava
            [chem_email] => abhishek@gmail.com
            [chemist_code] => chem001
            [chem_mobile] => 2147483647
            [prod_id] => 1
            [product_name] => Paracitamol
            [unit] => 10
            [pts] => 20
            [scheme] => no scheme
        )

    [1] => Array
(
            [MRID] => 1
            [MSR_Name] => John
            [MSR_email] => john@gmail.com
            [MSR_mobile] => 9000000008
            [MSR_hqdetail] => kjjh
            [hqdetail_id] => 1
            [doctor_id] => 2
            [dr_msl_no] => DOC000013
            [doctor_name] => Dipak Raichura
            [dr_email] => dipakraichura@gmail.com
            [chemist_id] => 1
            [chemist_name] => Abhishek Srivastava
            [chem_email] => abhishek@gmail.com
            [chemist_code] => chem001
            [chem_mobile] => 2147483647
            [prod_id] => 1
            [product_name] => Paracitamol
            [unit] => 10
            [pts] => 20
            [scheme] => no scheme
        )
)
```

i want to manipulate the array and want result like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [MRID] => 1
                [MSR_Name] => John
                [MSR_email] => john@gmail.com
                [MSR_mobile] => 9000000008
                [MSR_hqdetail] => kjjh
                [hqdetail_id] => 1
                [doctors] => array(
                                [0] =>  Array(
                                        [doctor_id] => 1
                                        [dr_msl_no] => DOC000012
                                        [doctor_name] => Y K Singh
                                        [dr_email] => yksingh@gmail.com
                                        [chemist]  =>Array(
                                                        [0] => Array(
                                                            [chemist_id] => 1
                                                            [chemist_name] => Abhishek Srivastava
                                                            [chem_email] => abhishek@gmail.com
                                                            [chemist_code] => chem001
                                                            [chem_mobile] => 2147483647
                                                            [product]  =>Array(
                                                                    [0] => Array(
                                                                        [prod_id] => 1
                                                                        [product_name] => Paracitamol
                                                                        [unit] => 10
                                                                        [pts] => 20
                                                                        [scheme] => no scheme
                                                                    )
                                                                )
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                    )
                                [1] => Array(
                                        [doctor_id] => 2
                                        [dr_msl_no] => DOC000013
                                        [doctor_name] => Dipak Raichura
                                        [dr_email] => dipakraichura@gmail.com
                                        [chemist]  =>Array(
                                                        [0] => Array(
                                                            [chemist_id] => 2
                                                            [chemist_name] => chemist2
                                                            [chem_email] => chemist2@gmail.com
                                                            [chemist_code] => chem002
                                                            [chem_mobile] => 7656564565
                                                            product]  =>Array(
                                                                    [0] => Array(
                                                                        [prod_id] => 2
                                                                        [product_name] => Crocin
                                                                        [unit] => 10
                                                                        [pts] => 20
                                                                        [scheme] => no scheme
                                                                    )
                                                                )
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                    )
                                )



            )


    )
```

Please help me how can i get the correct result, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to loop through your array and put the values in a new array using the desired keys.

Comment: Will the query result contain only one MRID value?

Answer (score 0):

The CodeIgniter [Array Helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/array_helper.html) comes in handy for these kinds of problems.  It will need to be loaded before this will work.

```
$this->load->helper('array');
```

Array Helper can use an array of keys to extract new arrays from an existing array. So make arrays of the keys you are interested in.

```
    $id = ['MRID', 'MSR_Name', 'MSR_email', 'MSR_mobile', 'MSR_hqdetail', 'hqdetail_id'];
    $aDoc = ['doctor_id', 'dr_msl_no', 'doctor_name', 'dr_email'];
    $aChemist = [ 'chemist_id', 'chemist_name', 'chem_email', 'chemist_code', 'chem_mobile'];
    $aproduct = [ 'prod_id', 'product_name', 'unit', 'pts', 'scheme'];
```

Then you extract sub-arrays and recombine them to meet your spec.
The variable `$results` used below is the array returned from your query.

```
    foreach($results as $value)
    {
      $chemist = elements($aChemist, $value);
      $chemist['product'] = elements($aproduct, $value);
      $doctor = elements($aDoc, $value);
      $doctor['chemist'] = $chemist;
      $doctors[] = $doctor;
    }

    $MRID[] = elements($id, $results[0]);
    $MRID['doctors'] = $doctors;
```

The array `$MIRD` should now contain the outcome you specified.

If there is more than one `MRID` in `$results` then additional code will be needed to extract them separately.

While this is relatively compact I'm inclined to think you might want to design a query statement that produces results closer to your ultimate need.